# WordNet lemmatizer in NLTK: what is the correct lemma for "boss"?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet, lemmatization

I use `nltk` 3.0.4 and notice that lemmas for words `boss` and `bosses` are different.

```python
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer

wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()

print wnl.lemmatize("boss", "n")
# returns "bos"

print wnl.lemmatize("bosses", "n")
# returns "boss"
```

From my point of view it's a weird behavior especially that `boss` is a [known word](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=boss) in WordNet and there is a [rule](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html) to keep `ss`.

Does anyone have an explanation or this is just a bug? How I should deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

1. After checking the [code](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.html#WordNetCorpusReader.morphy) (`_morphy()`) that generates the possible analyses for a given word, I found that there is no rule included to keep `ss`.
2. `Bos` is also a base form in wordnet.

Substitution rules:

```
MORPHOLOGICAL_SUBSTITUTIONS = {
    NOUN: [('s', ''), ('ses', 's'), ('ves', 'f'), ('xes', 'x'),
           ('zes', 'z'), ('ches', 'ch'), ('shes', 'sh'),
           ('men', 'man'), ('ies', 'y')],
    VERB: [('s', ''), ('ies', 'y'), ('es', 'e'), ('es', ''),
           ('ed', 'e'), ('ed', ''), ('ing', 'e'), ('ing', '')],
    ADJ: [('er', ''), ('est', ''), ('er', 'e'), ('est', 'e')],
    ADV: []}
```

Calling `print wnl.lemmatize("boss", "n")`:

Since a suitable base form ([`Bos`](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=Bos&i=0&h=0#c)) can be found when applying the substitution rules, it is returned. If this had not been included in wordnet the the lemma for `boss` would be `boss` since no shorter form can be found.

Comment: Yes, this is that i also have found ```bos``` if one of forms: ```print wordnet.synsets("boss", "n")```. What do you think, should be ``ss`` added to ```MORPHOLOGICAL_SUBSTITUTIONS```?

Comment: Maybe there are reasons why it was not added in the first place, maybe not :) According to the documentation, the code was adapted from [pywordnet](http://osteele.com/projects/pywordnet/). Maybe you find a clue there. Finally, you can always raise an issue on the [nltk github](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug.  If a word that ends in "s" is the singular form of a noun, that word should always be returned as one of the answers when doing noun lemmatization.  That's the case with boss, loss, moss, lens, etc. If "len" is a singular noun, it should be returned as well. But there's an additional issue. When removing the "s" reveals a existing stem, "bos" in this case, that stem should NOT end in "s".  The "e" insertion spelling rule which applies to words that end in "s', "z", "x", "ch", and "sh", would make th
e plural of "bos" be "boses".  That certainly seems like a better guess at the plural of this outlier than "boss".  The constraint that needs to be implemented is that the stem, unless it is marked as irregular, should produce the input form when run through the plural spelling rules. Since "bos" does not give "boss" when the spelling rules are applied, it should not be analyzed as the singular of "boss".